# SSIS reading operating system environment variables

Tags: ssis, script-task

On a Windows system, when I open a DOS command window, I can retrieve the value of operating system environment variable by running this:

C:\Users\me>set MyApplicationEnvironment
MyApplicationEnvironment=Staging

I would like to do the same thing in a SSIS environment.  Does anyone have any ideas on an optimal approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an SSIS variable of type String, MyApplicationEnvrionment

Add a Script Task and specify that the @[User::MyApplicationEnvironment] is a read/write variable.

Assuming C#, the content of the Main would look something like

```
var env = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyApplicationEnvironment");
if (env != null)
{
    Dts.Variables["User::MyApplicationEnvironment"].Value = env;
}
// TODO: what should happen if the variable is not found
```

[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-3.1)

We assign it to the .Value property of the Dts variable we're looking to update.